# Featured Images missing on migrated site

Tags: post-thumbnails, migration

I have just moved my blog from one host to another. I did this using the standard import/export method and got the new installation to copy across all the attached images. The only difference is that the new host is running Wordpress multi-site.

The migration worked but the featured images are not showing. This seems to be because the_post_thumbnail() is now suggesting a different size to the old site and therefore the image file doesn't exist. This is all with the same theme - twentythirteen.

You can see the issue here. This is the old site:

```
http://neilthompson.co.uk/2014/10/10/italy-2014-day-6-and-back-again/
```

and this is the same page on the new site:

```
http://54.171.135.229/neilthompson/2014/10/10/italy-2014-day-6-and-back-again/
```

Can anyone explain why this happening and how I can get it to show the images?

I did try changing the post.php and content.php entries as follows:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(604,270)); ?>
```

Which does display the image but the proportions are wrong. Also I don't really want to be customising the standard theme.

Comment: Obvious question: have you tried disabling all plugins and/or do you have a plugin that rewrites the img src on your pages (on either site old or new)?

Comment: Good question. The plugins are the same on both sites but I tried deactivating on new site with no change.

Comment: If you have access to the raw database, can you see what the page looks like (on both sites) before WP tweaks it?

Comment: Yes the postmeta entry for each is different - the sizes listed are different. That means that the import process is bust imho which is a pain.

Comment: Have you tried moving your complete upload folder. On the other hand, you can use a plugin like Force Regenerative Thumbnails to regenerate all your custom thumbnail sizes

Comment: Can't you just update the postmeta entries from the old db to the new db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the quickest and easiest way to resolve this is to add and run the plugin Regenerate Thumbnails as Pieter Goosen suggested. Back up your db first!